# Pointer Realloc not allocating

Tags: c, pointers, realloc

```
// FUNCTION 

int load_monsters_csv(monster_s **monsters, FILE *fp) {
int num_read = 0;
char buffer[MAX_LEN] = { 0 };

while (fgets(buffer, MAX_LEN, fp)) {
    trim(buffer);

    // For each item, you will need to reallocate the data to support 1 more.
    *monsters = realloc(*monsters, (num_read + 1) * sizeof(monster_s));

    // Complete the function by parsing the csv line and storing the data into each monster_s entry.
    parse_monster(*monsters + num_read, buffer);
    num_read++;
}

free(monsters);

return num_read;
}

// MAIN

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "utils.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int num_monsters = 0;

// Verify command line arguments.
if (argc != 2) {
    printf("Must include a file name\n");
    return 1;
}

// TODO: Attempt to open a CSV file given by the command line arguments.
FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
monster_s *monsters[MAX_MONSTERS];

// TODO: Load all the data with `load_monsters_csv`.
num_monsters = load_monsters_csv(monsters, fp);

// TODO: Print the data to verify that it was loaded.
for(int i = 0; i < num_monsters; i++) {
    printf("%s (%s), %d HP, %d AC, %d STR, %d DEX, %d CON\n", 
    monsters[i]->name, monsters[i]->type, monsters[i]->hp, monsters[i]->ac, 
    monsters[i]->str, monsters[i]->dex, monsters[i]->con);
}

// TODO: Be sure to free any allocated memory.
free(monsters);
fclose(fp);

return 0;
}
```

My file compiles but whenever I try to run it with the data that I have it states that the pointer being realloc'd is not allocated. I'm not sure how to fix it. I have to get the data from the load monsters function to read the number of monsters and allocated data for it which I thought I did properly.

Comment: `monster_s *monsters[MAX_MONSTERS];` declares an uninitialized array of `monster_s*`, and the passes it to `load_monsters_csv`. After reading a line, `load_monsters_csv` tries to `realloc` a pointer obtained from this uninitialized array. This is a violation of the requirements of `realloc`, which are that the first parameter must be `NULL` or the result of a previous call to `malloc` (or equivalent).

Comment: You are already declaring an array large enough for `MAX_MONSTERS` monsters.  Does the name `MAX_MONSTERS` mean something different from what it sounds like it means?

Comment: I think you want: `monster_s *monsters[MAX_MONSTERS];` to be `monster_s *monsters = NULL` and then do `num_monsters = load_monsters_csv(&monsters, fp);`